# Ionic side scroll bar not working with Samsung S6

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, samsung-mobile

I am facing very weird issue. Working on mobile application using Ionic and Angularjs. Things are pretty good but all of a sudden side menu scrollbar become sluggish. It will be easy to pin point things but issue is only coming with Samsung S6 (Android 5.x). S4 it is good. Any other mobile with Android 5.X version it is good. iOS working great. Just specific mobile it is not good.

I am creating dynamic menu based on response, I tried to do it hard code way but nothing helps. Also cross check digest timing that is also in ms. So, I doubt that can be issue.

I can't even pin point the issue to solve it. As things are very much specific to this mobile.

Any idea to debug it or way I can get and/or provide more info.

Let me know if any further information is required.

**PS:** I tried fresh ionic application with side menu, there it is working good on S6.

Comment: i had faced same kind of problem..!when we had used 'card' in UI..!try removing if u are using..!try to change UI part..it might take some..time in binding..!

Comment: @the_mahasagar I ll have a look and post a update.